# How to update URL address using ASP when based on JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object, url

I'm making an application of a list of races in a table, this information is gotten from a JSON api. Upon selecting a race in a table I need a window to pop up with the name of the race in the url address bar, so something like asp?=race_name at the end.

How would I go about completing this?

I've looked this up but can't seem to find an answer, my guess is I'm googling the wrong thing as I'm not good at explaining

```
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(jsonObj[i].id).onclick = function () {
        var newWin = window.open("","","width=700,height=700");
        newWin.onload = function () {
            var doc = newWin.document; // Create new document in window

            var raceName = document.createElement('h3');
            var distance = document.createElement('p');
            var location = document.createElement('p');
            var curPos = document.createElement('p');
            var difference = document.createElement('p');

            raceName.textContent = jsonObj[i].race_name;
            distance.textContent = jsonObj[i].distance;
            location.textContent = jsonObj[i].venue_name;

            doc.body.appendChild(raceName);
            doc.body.appendChild(distance);
            doc.body.appendChild(location);
    }
}
```

Here the window pops up and includes the correct information, I now just need to include code that would update the url address to include race name.

Comment: Why not add an endpoint to your site, an actual `race.asp?id=x`? If it simply prints the HTML you're creating manually, you can ditch all that code and simply call `window.open("race.asp?id=x", ...);`

Comment: I assumed this is something that should be done in different/proper code as I'm doing this for homework, is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes; you're basically jumping through hoops in order to simulate a much simpler mechanism. Create a simple ASP page that grabs the `id` GET param and displays the according race information. Then simply open a window using `"race.asp?id=" + i` as the URL.